# How do I change the page name, text or value in Kooboo CMS?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kooboo

I created a Kooboo CMS website with Simpler_Files Template. I navigated through the admin panel looking for how to change the page name / navigation menu text.

In the official documentation of Kooboo I couldn't find how to change the navigation menu texts as wel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

1. I went to localhost:8923/admin -- Admin Panel
2. Clicked on Pages
3. Clicked on a particular page
4. Clicked on "Navigation" tab
5. Filled in the "Display text" textbox with the desired text.
6. Finally I saved my modifications.